# onLongPress gesture for Polygon in Google Maps for Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I have a polygon in Google Map which uses `Polygon` class and it gets added to Map using `polygons` property of `GoogleMap` widget.

Currently, **Polygon can consume only Tap events** but I want to consume **Long Press events on the Polygon**.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap this Polygon widget in a GestureDetector and pass a callback function to onLongPress. Something like that:

```
GestureDetector(
  onLongPress: <your-callback-func>,
  child: Polygon()
)
```

Comment: Polygon is not a type of Widget class. https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/Polygon-class.html

Comment: Oh you are right. Sorry about that. I searched the docs and i guess that's simply not implemented :(